# EmberJS linkTo works but not transitionTo

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have routes defined as below

```
  this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'}, function() {
        this.route('details');
        this.route('members');
    });     
  });
```

*projects* displays a list of projects. On clicking a project I transition to *project.details* in ProjectsIndexRoute. But the model is not set to the clicked project. However if I create a link using *linkTo* to *project.details* then everything works.

See http://jsbin.com/ELaxigE/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the model. If you were to log `c` in your `open` action handler, you would see that it's undefined. Change this in your template ...

```
{{action 'open' on='click'}}
```

to this...

```
{{action 'open' this on='click'}}
```

Comment: Can you tell me, I wrote {{#linkTo 'project.details' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}. But there is no template with id="project/details". Why is it not throwing error and rendering "project" template instead. Strangely adding "project/details" does not work! See http://jsbin.com/ELaxigE/19/edit

Comment: Asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292439/how-does-emberjs-select-template-for-a-route

Answer (score 1):

Your event is expecting to be passed a project, but you are not specifying one in the action helper. Instead of `{{action 'open' on='click'}}`, you need to do:

```
{{action 'open' this on='click'}}
```

(Also, `on='click'` is unnecessary. It is the default behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Both answer till now where correct from @LukeMelia & @JonathanTran, that you need to provide a `model` for your `action` call, but no one provided actually a proof for it, here it is: http://jsbin.com/ELaxigE/18/edit.

Hope it helps.