# How does EmberJS select template for a Route?

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have these routes defined:

```
this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'}, function() {
        this.route('details');
        this.route('members');
    });     
});
```

What I thought was that by convention project.details route would look for "project/details" template. It does but strangely it does not get the correct model. See http://jsbin.com/ELaxigE/19/edit

Now instead of providing "project/details" template if I create "project" template then it works. See http://jsbin.com/ELaxigE/21/edit

I am confused what is happening. Can someone explain?

Comment: I have answered your question, sorry by my english. If you have any doubt, please give me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a route. When the model hook ins't defined, and have a dynamic segment that ends with `_id`:

```
this.route('edit', { path: ':user_id' });
```

This will generate a route like this:

```
App.EditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.User.find(params.id);
  }
});
```

In your case the only dynamic segmented route is `project`, because the `:project_id`.

```
this.resource('project', { path: ':project_id'}, function() { ... });
```

So because `details` and `members`, are just normal routes, it doesn't have a `model`.

When you change the template `project/details` to `project`, the things work because:

You transition to `project.details`, first is transitioned to `project` route, since you have declared `this.resource('project'...)`. And because it's a dynamic segmented route, the `App.Project` instance is returned, and the your template is rendered bound to this `model`.

After this, the child route `project.details` is transitioned, but this time, the template `project.details` not exist. So nothing is rendered.

I think that the solutions are the @alexspeller answer, or:

```
this.resource('project', function() {
    this.route('details', { path: 'details/:project_id' });
    this.route('members', { path: 'members/:project_id' });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with templates. You haven't defined the model for the ProjectDetails route. You can do so like this:

```
App.ProjectDetailsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('project');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok.. so I need to do this manually. I thought the 2nd parameter in transitionTo would be used as the model? What is the 2nd parameter used for then - only to generate the hash segments?